# On clicking over the desired polygon using getFeatureInfoUrl of openlayers 6, Why the tile layer (WMS) is showing values of the adjacent polygon?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, web-mapping, getfeatureinfo

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){

    //Geoserver dynamic layer 
    // wmsSource = indialayersource

    var india_dist_rainfall_layer_source = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/agrodss/wms",
        params: {"LAYERS":" agrodss:Rainfall", "tiled": true},
        serverType: "geoserver"
    })

    // wmsLayer = indialayer

    var india_dist_rainfall_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: india_dist_rainfall_layer_source, 
        opacity: 0.0,
        visible:true,
        title: "Agrodss_WMS"
    })


    var india_state_layer_source = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function(extent) {
      return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/agrodss/wfs?service=WFS&' + 
             'version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&' +
             'typeName=agrodss:india_boundary_updated_GCS&maxFeatures=500&' + 
             'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
             'bbox=' +
      extent.join(',') +
      ',EPSG:4326'
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bboxStrategy
    });
    
    var india_state_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
       source: india_state_layer_source,
       opacity: 0.5,
       visible:false,
       title: "Agrodss_WFS"
    });

    //Geoserver static base layer 
    // wmsSource = indialayersource

    var india_state_layer_WMS_source = new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/agrodss/wms",
      params: {"LAYERS":"   agrodss:india_boundary_updated_GCS", "tiled": true},
      serverType: "geoserver"
  })

  // wmsLayer = indialayer

  var india_state_layer_WMS = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: india_state_layer_WMS_source, 
      opacity: 1.0,
      visible:true,
      title: "State_boundary_WMS"
  })


  var india_717_dist_layer_source = new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/agrodss/wms",
    params: {"LAYERS":" agrodss:IMD_IND_DIST_717_GCS", "tiled": true},
    serverType: "geoserver"
})

// wmsLayer = indialayer

var india_717_dist_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: india_717_dist_layer_source, 
    opacity: 0.8,
    visible:true,
    title: "District_boundary_WMS"
})

    // view = myview

      var myview = new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: [77, 24],
            //center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([80, 22]),
            zoom: 4.5, 
            maxZoom: 8,
            minZoom: 3,
            //resolution:40070,
            smoothResolutionConstraint:true,
            //extent: [60, 6, 100, 40],
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [india_dist_rainfall_layer, india_717_dist_layer, india_state_layer, india_state_layer_WMS],
        target: 'js-map',
        view: myview,
      });


      map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var myviewResolution = myview.getResolution();
        var url = india_dist_rainfall_layer_source.getFeatureInfoUrl(
          evt.coordinate,
          myviewResolution,
          'EPSG:4326',
          {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': '5'}
        );
        if (url) {
          fetch(url)
            .then(function (response) { return response.text(); })
            .then(function (html) {
              document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = html;
            });
        }
      });
    
      map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        var hit = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(pixel, function () {
          return true;
        });
        map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
      });



    map.on('click', function(e){
        console.log(e.coordinate);


    })
}
```

In the HTML, when I am Keeping the height to 400px, then the value of desired polygon is fetched properly,

```
    <style>
    html, body, .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .map {
        position: relative;
    }
    </style>
```

[image: height: 400px;]

But as I change the height to some other value like to 300px or 500px, the value from the polygon does not give it's value,
rather the value of some different polygon shows up

```
    <style>
    html, body, .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .map {
        position: relative;
    }
    </style>
```

[image: height: 500px;]

like it is showing values of some nearby polygon, instead of the one on which I am clicking,

As here, I have clicked on the polygon of Sonipat, but it is fetching the data of Kurukshetra. How to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

You are providing 3 key elements of information to your `GetFeatureInfo` request builder, evt.coordinate,
myviewResolution,
'EPSG:3857'. Since your answer is wrong the most likely problem is one of these three values. In the code dump you provided there was no mention of `myviewResolution` being set to a value but it is most likely that you should be getting this information from the map. Infact a quick google of `openlayers get resolution` suggests that using `view.getResolution()` would provide the required value.

Comment: The view resolution is set by `var myviewResolution = myview.getResolution();` which looks correct.  The deleted code may be relevant since it includes `"LAYERS":" agrodss:Rainfall"`  If there are no rainfall records for the position clicked the nearest 5 will be returned, which may be in another state.

Comment: Nope, that's not how getFeatureInfo works, it will only return features (to maxFeatures) that contain the I,J pixel in the request.

Comment: The earlier code was fine, its because of the style of map, when i am changing the height, then this issue is coming, else, when i am keeping the height to 400px, then it is returning the correct values,   <!-- <style>
        .map {
          width: 100%;
          height:400px;
        }
    </style> -->